# Command substitution is adding a newline?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, newlines

I have a script that queries the device architecture from an android device, and uses that in a path to push a file to the device.

The code is similar to this:

```
ARCH=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi)
adb push libs/"$ARCH"/binary /data/local/tmp/binary
```

However, the path gets mangled. When piping the `getprop` command to a file, I can see that it returns a newline, which is probably the cause of the problem. I was under the impression that command substitution strips newlines, but either way, I tried:

```
 ARCH=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi | tr -d '\n')
```

with still no luck.

Any ideas/

Comment: It strips *trailing* newlines; "interior" newlines are preserved.

Comment: What is the output of the `adb` command, and what is the output of `printf '%q\n' "$ARCH"`?

Comment: @chepner: adb outputs `armeabi-v7a`, the printf outputs `$'armeabi-v7a\r'`

Comment: You don't have a newline; you have a carriage return, which the command substitution does not strip.

Comment: @chepner so using `tr -d '\r'` would be the way to go...

Comment: It's one way, although unnecessarily expensive. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adb` outputs a command with a DOS line ending. The command substitution strips the newline character, but not the carriage return; you'll have to strip that manually.

```
ARCH=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi)
ARCH=${ARCH%$'\r'}
adb push libs/"$ARCH"/binary /data/local/tmp/binary
```

Comment: I'm actually using an `adb` server on Windows, but running the script from Ubuntu (on Windows). I wonder if `adb` is conforming to Windows standards, but would return `\n` if it was running on linux.